# Using bash script to move folders based on their name

Tags: linux, bash, grep, find, xargs

I have a file (list.txt) with a list of directories in it, I want to read each line & then move the folders to a specific destination folder based on a number range in the directories name. It needs to work no matter how many directories are listed in the file because this will change daily.

In list.txt each line lists the directories like so;

/20211601_113212_hello_LGD_text.csv/KLS_8938I1_0202**0721**_1/

I'm interested in the text in bold only, if that number is in a certain range e.g. 1-500 I want to move it to 'folder1', or 500-100 'folder2' and so on. The number will always precede the _1/ & will always be 4 numbers.

Using

```
grep -0 '......$' /list.txt | cut -d_ -f1
```

I've managed to grep the number I want, but I haven't been able to do anything with that information. I'm thinking I could split out each line into separate files & then use a for loop to iterate through each file, but I don't know how that would exactly work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried using bash's [conditional expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html)? For comparing numbers see the last section which starts with `arg1 OP arg2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
declare -i number
while IFS= read -r directory; do
  ((number = 10#"${directory: -7:-3}"))
  echo mv "${directory%/}" "folder$(((number + 499) / 500))/"
done < list.txt
```

- The syntax highlighting above malfunctions, `#` is **not** a start of a comment in this case.
- The `for`-cycle reads whole lines without messing with spaces and without considering backslash escapes. This is to make sure that the directory names can be (almost) arbitrary.
- We extract the number by starting at the 7. character from the end and ending before the 3. character from the end (both 1-based). Alternatively, the `_1/` could be also stripped using `${directory%_1/}`.
- We treat the number as an integer (`declare -i`) and make sure it is **not** interpreted as an octal number (`10#`), because otherwise integer literals starting with `0` are octal (e.g. `$((08))` yields an error).
- We generate the `mv` command — **remove the `echo` once satisfied with the output** — where `${directory%/}` strips the final slash (which you may want to tweak) and then `$(((number + 499) / 500))` generates the required 1-based “folder” number, so e.g. `499` yields `1`, `500` yields (still) `1`, `501` yields `2` etc. You will need to tweak that to your liking.

Comment: Nice! Why do you strip the final slash and add one at the end of `folder_N/`? And according the OP specification there is no underscore between `folder` and the number.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Good catch with the underscore; edited. As for the final slash, there are tools (other than `mv`) where a final slash means “move the contents of the directory” rather than the whole directory. So I usually tend to avoid the final slash everywhere, whether it matters or not.

Comment: I see. On the other hand, if by accident it is a file, not a directory, there would be an error instead of a silent file move. So the final slash in the source name can be considered as a safety measure.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Actually, a bigger issue with the file would be a clobbered name (without the last character). So I’ve edited it to `${directory%/}`, which only strips the slash if there is one. Otherwise I think it’s safe to assume, based on the question, that only directories will be listed in `list.txt`. But anyway, if the slash was actually missing, the substitution `${directory: -7:-3}` would also break. And making _that_ more resilient would over-complicate the answer, I guess.

Comment: Excellent, thanks @AndrejPodzimek. With a bit of tweaking on the folder names that is exactly what I needed. Thank you!